# Anonymizing data / replacing names

Tags: pandas, hash, anonymize

Normally I anonymize my data by using hashlib and using the .apply(hash) function.

Now im trying a new approach, imagine I have to following df called 'data':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'contributor':['eric', 'frank', 'john', 'frank', 'barbara'],
                   'amount payed':[10,28,49,77,31]})

  contributor  amount payed
0        eric            10
1       frank            28
2        john            49
3       frank            77
4     barbara            31
```

Which I want to anonymize by turning the names all into `person1`, `person2` etc, like this:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'contributor':['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person2', 'person4'],
                       'amount payed':[10,28,49,77,31]})

  contributor  amount payed
0     person1            10
1     person2            28
2     person3            49
3     person2            77
4     person4            31
```

So my first though was summarizing the **name** column so the names are attached to a unique index and I can use that index for the number after 'person'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think faster solution is use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) for unique values, add `1`, convert to `Series` and `string`s and prepend `Person` string:

```
df['contributor'] = 'Person' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['contributor'])[0] + 1).astype(str)
print (df)
  contributor  amount payed
0     Person1            10
1     Person2            28
2     Person3            49
3     Person2            77
4     Person4            31
```

Comment: This is actually really useful and fast method. Thank you for introducing me to factorize, ive never used it before!

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For stand-alone cases `factorize` works well; But, for the cases where anonymized values needs to maintain referential-integrity across some other data-frame column (basically to retain db-level referential relationship) then `hash` based approach will be safer. [reference-safe-anonym-util-gist](https://gist.github.com/joshuamosesb/b68c3fd9ef84c33a6f6ff9330ecde35e)

Answer (score 1):

```
labels, uniques =  pd.factorize(df['name'])
labels = ['person_'+str(l) for l in labels]
df['contributor_anonymized'] = labels
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to create a data frame called "index" for this operation and keep unique `name` values inside it?

Then produce masks with unique name indexes and merge the resulting data frame `index`with `data`.

```
index = pd.DataFrame()
index['name'] = df['name'].unique()
index['mask'] = index['name'].apply(lambda x : 'person' + 
str(index[index.name == x].index[0] + 1))

data.merge(index, how='left')[['mask', 'amount']]
```