# Anonymise pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say, I have the following data frame.

```
Person_info
(Bob, 2)
(John, 1)
(Bek, 10)
(Bob, 6)
```

I would like to anonymise by just keeping their value.

```
Person_info
(Person 1, 2)
(Person 2, 1)
(Person 3, 10)
(Person 1, 6)
```

I got simple way to anonymise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309060/anonymizing-data-replacing-names) but it can't help what I want to get.

Can any one help with this in Pandas Python?

Comment: Is this one column or are these two columns?

Comment: It is one column.

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(df["Person_info"].iloc[0]))`?

Comment: I can see the result ```<class 'str'>```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309060/anonymizing-data-replacing-names) you can make use of `strip()` and `split()` method:

```
out=df['Person_info'].str.strip('()| ').str.split(',',1,expand=True)
```

Then use `factorize()` method as per by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321470/14289892):

```
out[0]='Person' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(out[0])[0] + 1).astype(str)
```

Finally use `agg()` method:

```
df['Person_info']=out.agg(tuple,1)
```

Output of `df`:

```
    Person_info
0   (Person1, 2)
1   (Person2, 1)
2   (Person3, 10)
3   (Person1, 6)
```

Comment: When I run your code, I got result some thing like this in one of the row ```(Person1, , None, None, None)```.

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly check **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Cast your `names` to category and get the category codes ;)

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame(
[('Bob', 2),
('John', 1),
('Bek', 10),
('Bob', 6)], columns=['name','valuex'])

dataf["name"] = dataf["name"].astype("category").cat.codes.map(lambda x: f"Person {x}")

print(dataf)
```

#### output

```sh
       name  valuex
0  Person 1       2
1  Person 2       1
2  Person 0      10
3  Person 1       6
```

### Update:

```py
…
dataf["Person_info"] = [info for info in dataf.itertuples(index=False, name=None)]
```

### Output:

```sh
       name  valuex     Person_info
0  Person 1       2   (Person 1, 2)
1  Person 2       1   (Person 2, 1)
2  Person 0      10  (Person 0, 10)
3  Person 1       6   (Person 1, 6)
```

Comment: OP wants persons 1, 2, 3, 1. Not 1, 2, 0, 1.

Comment: Could it be possible keeping in one column like I showed in the question? Since my challenge is that one.

Comment: Just use `itertuples` ;)